# Reddit install "Cannot find Cython. Skipping Cython build."

Tags: python, cython, reddit

I'm trying to download the open source version of reddit to play with it.

I'm following: https://github.com/reddit/reddit/wiki/Install-guide

But I'm getting an error:

```
Cannot find Cython. Skipping Cython build.
```

When running:

```
python setup.py build
```

I'm on a Mac Pro with Yosemite if that makes a difference.

What am I doing wrong? I Googled "Cannot find Cython. Skipping Cython build reddit" but I didn't seem to see anything related except the actual exception in https://github.com/reddit/reddit/blob/master/r2/setup.py

The closest thing I found was just looking at Cython: http://docs.cython.org/src/quickstart/install.html which lists:

> Mac OS X To retrieve gcc, one option is to install Apple’s XCode,
>   which can be retrieved from the Mac OS X’s install DVDs or from
>   http://developer.apple.com.

However I have a recent and updated computer with xcode dev tools installed. What am I missing?

Comment: Is Cython installed? What happens when you  `>>> import Cython` If you get an ImportError, you need to install it. `pip install cython`

Comment: Hmm, I did python, then import cython ... it just went to the next line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I manually installed it with:

```
easy_install cython
```

I was unable to resolve why it was not included with xcode as the Cython instructions state.

Comment: Cython and gcc are not the same: the former is a Python module that depends on the latter. The instructions you posted for Mac OS X states *To retrieve gcc...*, not to retrieve Cython. TL;DR: you need to install it, which you did.